# Slider slides are not aligned?

Tags: jquery, html, css, slider, carousel

I have a slider for images that I converted into text to fade quotes in and out, for some reason everytime it loads the new slide, it flashes it at the bottom of the container and then movies it up. Does anyone have any idea what this could be?

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eu1rqh1z/)

HTML:

```
<section id="slider" class="container">
<ul class="slider-wrapper">
<li class="current-slide">
<div class="quote">This is a product quote and testimonial.. blah blah blah, DonorPro is very good, <span>blah blah blah, DonorPro is very good</span>.
<div class="author">Random Company/Orgainization&nbsp;</div>
</div>
</li>
<li>
<div class="quote">This is a product quote and testimonial.. blah blah blah, DonorPro is very good, <span>blah blah blah, DonorPro is very good</span>.
<div class="author">Random Company/Orgainization 2&nbsp;</div>
</div>
</li>
<li>
<div class="quote">This is a product quote and testimonial.. blah blah blah, DonorPro is very good, <span>blah blah blah, DonorPro is very good</span>.
<div class="author">Random Company/Orgainization 3&nbsp;</div>
</div>
</li>
</ul>
</section>
```

JS:

```
$(function() {

     var SliderModule = (function() {
        var pb = {};
        pb.el = $('#slider');
        pb.items = {
            panels: pb.el.find('.slider-wrapper > li'),
        }

        var SliderInterval,
            currentSlider = 0,
            nextSlider = 1,
            lengthSlider = pb.items.panels.length;

        pb.init = function(settings) {
            this.settings = settings || {duration: 8000};
            var items = this.items,
                lengthPanels = items.panels.length,
                output = '';

            for(var i = 0; i < lengthPanels; i++) {
                if(i == 0) {
                    output += '<li class="active"></li>';
                } else {
                    output += '<li></li>';
                }
            }

            activateSlider();
            $('#control-buttons').on('click', 'li', function(e) {
                var $this = $(this);
                if(!(currentSlider === $this.index())) {
                    changePanel($this.index());
                }
            });

        }

        var activateSlider = function() {
            SliderInterval = setInterval(pb.startSlider, pb.settings.duration);
        }

        // Funcion para la Animacion
        pb.startSlider = function() {
            var items = pb.items,
                controls = $('#control-buttons li');
            // Comprobamos si es el ultimo panel para reiniciar el conteo
            if(nextSlider >= lengthSlider) {
                nextSlider = 0;
                currentSlider = lengthSlider-1;
            }

            controls.removeClass('active').eq(nextSlider).addClass('active');
            items.panels.eq(currentSlider).fadeOut('slow');
            items.panels.eq(nextSlider).fadeIn('slow');

            currentSlider = nextSlider;
            nextSlider += 1;
        }

        var changePanel = function(id) {
            clearInterval(SliderInterval);
            var items = pb.items,
                controls = $('#control-buttons li');

            if(id >= lengthSlider) {
                id = 0;
            } else if(id < 0) {
                id = lengthSlider-1;
            }

            controls.removeClass('active').eq(id).addClass('active');
            items.panels.eq(currentSlider).fadeOut('slow');
            items.panels.eq(id).fadeIn('slow');


            currentSlider = id;
            nextSlider = id+1;

            activateSlider();
        }

        return pb;
     }());

     SliderModule.init({duration: 5000});

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey I think the thing is that you are doing this

```
items.panels.eq(nextSlider).fadeOut('slow');
items.panels.eq(nextSlider).fadeIn('slow');
```

what I did was to hide it automatically and fadeIn.

```
items.panels.eq(currentSlider).hide();
items.panels.eq(nextSlider).fadeIn('slow');
```

here's the JSFiddle code: http://jsfiddle.net/eu1rqh1z/3/

Comment: I see! That works perfectly, thank you so much for the quick answer!
(will accept answer in 7mins since I can't accept it yet)

Answer (score 0):

This happens because both slides are displayed in the wrapper at the same time. That made the second one go to the next line, because of natural html flow

A solution is to make the wrapper relative, and the slides absolute, so that one would disappear while the other appears, and still be at the right position.

```
.slider-wrapper > li {
    position: absolute;
}
```

JSFiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/eu1rqh1z/4/